# QT does not respond using a while loop

Tags: c++, qt, while-loop

I've searched around without luck to get the answer to this question.

I'm doing a UART communication, I want to read data continuously if I have the button pressed or in the "down" position. The problem is that I'm using a while loop to do it. When I try to stop reading and release the button, the program freezes and does not respond. Any help will be appreciated it. Part of the code is below.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_3_toggled(bool checked)
{
    while(checked)
    {
        QByteArray datas = Serial_port.readAll();
        ui->textEdit->setText((QString)datas);
        qDebug()<<"Im here";
        msleep(100);
        qDebug()<<datas;
        qDebug()<<checked;
    }


qDebug()<<checked;

}
```

Comment: See [QCoreApplication::processEvents](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents).

Comment: You're blocking the event loop, _of course_ it's going to block Qt from responding! If you want something to happen on a regular basis, you need to use a `QTimer`.

Comment: I assume `QSerialPort` has a signal that tells you when data is available so you likely don't need the while loop at all.

Comment: @drescherjm Yes, I have signal that tells me when data is available. How could I do it without using the while loop and keep reading continuously?

Comment: Put the read in a slot connected to the signal. Don't loop in that slot. Just readAll. Append the text to your widget instead of replacing it.

Comment: This is why threads are so useful. Try creating a worker thread that scans your serial port for data and, when its found something useful, package it up in a data object and send that to your GUI thread via a signal/slot connection

Answer (score 0):

why you need a loop to exec this code? are you using function connect() to made your click event correct? whem you click u start your loop and you don't have a end of this loop, you don't need this loop, you readall from serial port and put it in QBytearray when it finally readall the function read the next line and next at until end of function!

but if your need to continue using the loop try to made a checkbox in your ui, to get true or false and put a if in in loop to stop your loop

```
if(ui->cb->isChecked()) 
   checked = true; 
else 
   checked=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're blocking the event loop, therefore, Qt can't process events. You could try calling `QApplication::processEvents()` during your loop, and that should make the UI responsive again.